# Python str.lower() causes memory leak

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, memory-leaks

Initially I've noticed this problem when I worked with a huge DataFrame, tried to apply to str.lower() to string-features and it cost me 10 GB of memory.

I decided to investigate this problem on simplified example and that's what I've found:

At first check how much memory a process takes:

```
import sys
import psutil
from guppy import hpy
import gc

def print_in_mb(n):
    print(n // (1024 * 1024), 'Mb')

def print_object_size(obj):
    print_in_mb(sys.getsizeof(obj))

print_in_mb(psutil.Process().memory_info().rss)
64 Mb
```

Then create a fairly large tuple with strings:

```
a = tuple('HeLlO, WoRlD' for _ in range(10_000_000))
print_object_size(a)
76 Mb

print_in_mb(psutil.Process().memory_info().rss)
142 Mb
```

And then I want to convert each string to lower case:

```
a = tuple(x.lower() for x in a)
print_object_size(a)
76 Mb

print_in_mb(psutil.Process().memory_info().rss)
764 Mb
```

Boom! **After applying `.lower()` method a program takes 764 Mb of memory which is definitely exceed an amount of memory required to store created objects.**

Calling `gc.collect()` doesn't help:

```
gc.collect()
print_in_mb(psutil.Process().memory_info().rss)
764 Mb
```

Why calling `.lower()/.upper()` method takes so much memory? Are there any ways to avoid such an extra memory allocation?

PS This problem appears only while working with structures. If I create just a big string and then lower it - there is no extra memory allocation.

```
x = 'Aa' * 100_000_000
print_object_size(x) 
190 Mb

print_in_mb(psutil.Process().memory_info().rss)
955 Mb

y = x.lower()
print_object_size(x)
190 Mb

print_in_mb(psutil.Process().memory_info().rss)
1145 Mb - OK!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only looked at the size of the tuple and forgot to add the sizes of all the strings. One way to do that:

```
objs = dict(zip(map(id, a), a))
print_in_mb(sum(map(sys.getsizeof, objs.values())))
```

For your original strings tuple, that shows me `0 Mb`, as all the strings are the same single object. Because the string is in the source code, so Python interned it.

For your lowered strings tuple, that shows me `581 Mb`, as lowering creates new separate string objects.

You can reduce the memory usage by interning the strings:

```
a = tuple(sys.intern(x.lower()) for x in a)
```

For that, it shows me `0 Mb` again, as it's now again just a single string object repeated over and over again.

Why do you see an increase of 764 - 142 = 622 MB, not just 581 Mb? Mostly because objects are memory-aligned to addresses divisible by 16. So while your string's data (both content and metadata) is only 61 bytes (as `sys.getsizeof(a[0])` reports), it actually takes 64 bytes, 3 of which aren't used. And 64*10^7 / 2^20 is 610 "Mb", close to your 622 "Mb".

(Btw I suggest to properly use MB, i.e. divide by 1e6. Instead of calculating MiB and calling it "Mb". It would make the numbers much clearer. For example, the ten million strings taking 64 bytes each take 640 MB together.)